# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, but it's in my env path

Tags: node.js, powershell

I'm trying to launch on Windows a node.js module that I have written on Linux.

I have set the env path to nodejs, i have installed my dependencies, when i use npm alone it's working. But when I npm start my module, it's telling me this :

[image: my powershell prompt]

Here is my package.json's scripts :

[image]

Can someone explain to me what's wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue has to do with how <strike>`cmd`</strike> PowerShell and other Windows terminals treats single quoted strings, which in turn will get incorrectly parsed into `process.argv` in node.js.

This is indicative in the error message:

> `'npm` is not recognized (...)

which shows a leading `'` in front of the expected command `npm`

As a workaround, try using escaped double quotes instead of the single quote in your start script in `package.json`:

```
"start": "nodemon lib/index.js --exec \"npm run lint && babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2\" "
```

Comment: Since when uses PowerShell cmd?

Comment: @Clijsters you're right, PowerShell does not use cmd